# How do I schedule refresh of a Web.Contents data source?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, m, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to set a 'Scheduled Refresh' on a dataset in the Power BI web app (https://app.powerbi.com).

Normally I should see these options in the dataset settings:

[image]

But when I go to settings I am greeted by this warning:

[image]

and no way to select the 'Gateway Connection' or data source settings.

I found a useful article which explains a problem with Web.Contents and how to get around it:

https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/23/web-contents-m-functions-and-dataset-refresh-errors-in-power-bi/

I applied this and it still doesn't work.

In Power BI Desktop no data sources are listed as I am using a **hand-authored query**.
The way it works is there is a main query (**Log Scroll**) which calls a recursive function query (**RecursiveFetch**). The function then calls a Web API which works by sending a new page of JSON data everytime it is called, in a sort of 'scrolling' manner.

The **Log Scroll** query looks like this:

```
let
    url = "http://exampleURL:1000"
    Source = RecursiveFetch(url, 5, null, null)
in
    Source
```

The **RecursiveFetch** looks like this:

```
let
    RecursiveFetch= (url, scrollCount, scrollID, counter) =>

    let
        Counter = if (counter = null) then 0 else counter,
        Results = if (scrollID = null) then
            Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
                [
                    Headers=[
                        #"Authorization"="Basic <key here>",
                        #"Content-Type"="application/json"
                    ]
                ]
            ))
        else
            Json.Document(Web.Contents(url,
                [
                    Content = Text.ToBinary(scrollID),
                    Headers=[
                        #"Authorization"="Basic <key here>",
                        #"Content-Type"="application/json"
                    ]
                ]
            )),
        ParsedResults = Table.FromList(Results[hits][hits], Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

        Return = if (Counter < scrollCount) then
            ParsedResults & RecursiveFetch(url, scrollCount scrollID, Counter)
        else
            ParsedResults
    in
        Return
in
    RecursiveFetch
```

It all works perfectly in Power BI Desktop but when I publish it to the web app I get the errors shown above.

I have manually set up a data source in my Gateway Cluster which connects fine to the URL with the same credentials that the hand-authored query uses.

How do I get this all to work? Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

> It all works perfectly in Power BI Desktop but when I publish it to the web app I get the errors shown above.

To fix that, `Web.Contents` needs to use `options[RelativePath]` and `options[Query]` (or `Content` for HTTP POST)

The original:

```
"https://data.gov.uk/api/3/action/package_search?q=" & Term
```

Will use:

```
let
    BaseUrl = "https://data.gov.uk",
    Options = [
        RelativePath = "/api/3/action/package_search",
        Headers = [
            Accept="application/json"
        ],
        Query = [
            q = Term
        ]

    ],
    // wrap 'Response' in 'Binary.Buffer' if you are using it multiple times
    response = Web.Contents(BaseUrl, Options),
    buffered = Binary.Buffer(response),
    response_metadata = Value.Metadata(response),
    status_code = response_metadata[Response.Status],
    from_json = Json.Document(final_result)
in
    from_json
```

[the parameter `url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents) is going to be the minimum url possible, otherwise the service will think your dynamic request is actually unchanged -- causing the original refresh error.